# Dynamic data asp.net Query String parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Is there a way to define my own querystring parameter in Dynamic data rather then using something like

```
Edit.aspx?AccountID=1
```

I want to use something like this

```
Edit.aspx?id=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem

I simply added this on the pageload method of my edit page template

```
        string id = String.Empty;
        if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null ){
            id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
            DetailsDataSource.WhereParameters.Clear();
            DetailsDataSource.WhereParameters.Add("AccountID", DbType.Int32, id);
        }
```